# Test a function $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ for continuity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Given the function $$f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $(x,y) = (0,0) $ } \\
\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}, & \text{if $(x,y) \neq (0,0) $}
\end{cases}$$

I have to prove that $f$ is continuos in $(0,0)$. Using epsilon-delta criterion, I have to find  $\delta \gt 0$ for any given $\varepsilon \gt 0 $ , so that 
$\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \lt \delta \implies \frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2} \lt \varepsilon$ is fulfilled.

I calculated that $\delta \lt \sqrt{ \frac{\varepsilon}{y}(x^2+y^2) + y^2 }$ exactly fulfills the inequalities.

What bothers me is the term $\frac{\varepsilon}{y}(x^2+y^2) + y^2$ :
It isn't defined for $y=0$ and it can be negative for $ y \lt 0 $.

Now my question: is is possible to define $\delta$ by cases? Then I would get rid of the problem for $y \lt 0 $ .

$ \delta :=
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{\frac{\varepsilon}{-y}(x^2+y^2) + y^2},  & \text{if $ y \lt 0 $ } \\
\sqrt{\frac{\varepsilon}{y}(x^2+y^2) + y^2}, & \text{if $ y \gt 0 $}
\end{cases}$

But what to do with $y=0$ ?

Answer (score 1):

We only have to prove that $f\rightarrow0$ when $\left(x,y\right)\rightarrow0$.
We have :

$$0\leq \frac{x^2|y|}{x^2+y^2}=|x|\frac{|xy|}{x^2+y^2}\leq|x|\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2+y^2}=|x|$$
so that if $|x|\leq\delta$ for any $y$, then $|f\left(x,y\right)|\leq\delta$. Hence,
you can take the limit $\left(x,y\right)\rightarrow0$ and find $0=f\left(0,0\right)$.

To answer your last question, you can indeed find $\delta$ for the both cases $y>0$ and $y<0$, but you see here that it can be done in one time.

Comment: why do we only have to prove that $ f\rightarrow0$ when $\left(x,y\right)\rightarrow0$ ? This definition of continuity doesn't seem intuitive to me

Comment: It is because $f$ is a well-defined quotient of continuous functions when $\left(x,y\right)\neq\left(0,0\right)$, and then the less obvious point is why it is continuous at $\left(0,0\right)$. But if you're not familiar with the notion of continuity, you need to prove that $f$ is continuous even when $\left(x,y\right)\neq\left(0,0\right)$ with $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ criterion (or prove what I've said : a well-defined quotient of continuous functions is continuous).

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: $\left|\dfrac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}\right| \leq |y| \leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$